# Is my question a good fit for a bounty?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question 11 days ago, about a [bug in some apex code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117473/test-setcreateddate-fails-on-note-record-created-in-test-context), which was preventing me from being able to write a test class for a certain sObject type. It got a few views, and a solid answer with some workarounds, but I was really looking for someone who has experienced this issue before, or someone who could clarify it as a known issue.

I have considered putting this question up for bounty to get extra views, and hopefully additional replies, but I'm not sure that a bounty is a good fit for a question which is essentially a bug report, which led me here.

Is my question a good fit for a bounty?

Comment: If you want to know if it's a known issue, I recommend you visit https://trust.salesforce.com or tweet @asksalesforce on twitter.

Comment: That's exactly my view (and usage) of bounties.  I use them when I'm fishing for a concise answer to my problem , since that tends to elevate the question's value for me and others who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I have considered putting this question up for bounty **to get extra
>   views, and hopefully additional replies**

That right there is the pure concept of bounty, it's advertising your question out, without any guarantees of ROI. It's good to see you understand this.

If your question fits with what we consider on topic and no community flags to close it and you understand how the bounty system works ... there's no reason why bounty would not be appropriate.

So: **go for it**.